# Evaluate complex exponential expression

Tags: functions, evaluation, complex

I am trying to evaluate the modulus of the following expression. The expected result is 1.3. However, I tried Abs, ComplexExpand but still couldn't get it.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

> 1/(1+e^(-i135°))

```
N[ComplexExpand[Abs[1/(1 + E^((-I135)*Degree))]]]
```

Comment: There should be a space after `I`. Try this: `N[ComplexExpand[Abs[1/(1 + E^((-I 135)*Degree))]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT.** You have already been given the answer to your problem in the comments.

The [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) is unnecessary since there are no variables

The exact value is

```
Abs[1/(1 + E^((-I 135)*Degree))] // Simplify

(*  1/Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2]]  *)
```

The approximate numeric value is

```
% // N

(*  1.30656  *)
```